# Large inserts breaking indexed queries

Tags: sql-server, index

Very similar to https://serverfault.com/questions/163442/large-insert-update-in-table-causes-timeout-while-sql-server-re-arrange-indexes only I am not using SSIS with only occassional large (predominently annual) inserts from another staging table in a stored procedure and the target table is partitioned with data being written to an existing partition. All indexes are aligned.

I've tried setting AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC ON but that doesn't seem to help. Queries are still blocked for about 10 minutes while the indexing catches up even when they should use partition elimination and not hit the inserted data.

I'd rather have a fast but stale result than a time-out.

Even after

```
ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON
GO
ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC ON
GO
```

sp_helpdb MyDB.status

still reads

> Status=ONLINE, Updateability=READ_WRITE, UserAccess=MULTI_USER,
>   Recovery=SIMPLE, Version=655, Collation=Latin1_General_CI_AS,
>   SQLSortOrder=0, IsAutoCreateStatistics, IsAutoUpdateStatistics,
>   IsFullTextEnabled

Shouldn't it have something to indicate that async is on?

Is there anything else I can do to make sure queries aren't slowed down?

Comment: Have you reviewed the query plan to see if partition elimination is occurring as expected?  Have you identified if an auto statistics update is occurring after your inserts?  What wait type are you observing when your queries are slow?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  Is it why you aren't seeing partition elimination?  If so, see @SQLKiwi's blog post on the topic (http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/09/12/why-doesn-t-partition-elimination-work.aspx).  As for auto create stats asynchronously, the reason you don't see it there is because I believe that is just using `DATABASEPROPERTYEX()`, and there is no option to check for auto update states async.  Instead use the following query to verify: `select name, is_auto_update_stats_async_on from sys.databases where name = 'YourDb';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. It's because one of the columns in the partitioned table has a varchar(max). Limiting it to varchar(120) resolves to problem. It seems ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC ON requires the online index build.

I should have said I'm on 2008 R2

Thanks though.